# Topology on cartesian product and product topology

Tags: general-topology

Let X and Y be sets and let $\tau$ be topology on X$\times$Y. Then there are $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are topologies on X and Y , respectively such that $\mathcal B$={U$\times$V : U$\in$$\tau_1$ and V$\in$$\tau_2$} is basis for $\tau$ or not ? If it is true then I want to proof. But if not then I want to example.

Comment: How is "the topology on $X\times Y$" defined?

Comment: Didn't you [just ask a question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539073/topology-on-cartesian-product-and-product-topology) with two good counterexamples in the answer?

Comment: Arbitary. unfixed

Comment: Arthur.In before question I just not see your answer so I ask this new question.

Comment: Sorry Arthur.I misunderstood. I think that you are Arthur Fischer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all.If you have topologies $T_1,T_2$ of $X,Y$ respectively then the $\mathcal B$={U$\times$V : U$\in$$T_1$ and V$\in$$T_2$} is a basis for a topology in $X \times Y$ which is called product topology.

You ask the other direction.Just have in mind that for every basis there is a unique topology and for a topology there isn't a unique basis.So what you ask doesn't really stand.

For example if $X=Y=\Bbb R$ then $X \times Y=\Bbb R^2$ which is homeomorphic to $\Bbb C$ and the open sets there are the open disks and with your sayings you make it more difficult because then the disk would be described as the union of two product open intervals of $\Bbb R$,which is more complicated.
I mean that if you have something more complicated than $\Bbb C$ how would you break it in a product of Spaces?

Comment: This is Answer of Arthur Fischer.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539073/topology-on-cartesian-product-and-product-topology